# Apexcharts DataLabels

Tags: apexcharts

Can anyone help in displaying data labels on apex charts  I want to show data value instead of %value

I want to show the value 55 or 41 or something likewise on the data label how to do the formatting for this in data labels block

dataLabels: {
enabled: true,
textAnchor: "start",
style: {
colors: ["#fff"]
},
formatter: function(val, opt) {
return opt.w.globals.labels[opt.dataPointIndex] + ":  " + val;
},
offsetX: 0,
dropShadow: {
enabled: true
}
},

[image]
var options = {
series: [{
name: 'Marine Sprite',
data: [44, 55, 41, 37, 22, 43, 21]
}, {
name: 'Striking Calf',
data: [53, 32, 33, 52, 13, 43, 32]
}],
};

```
  [![Apex Charts datalabel ][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is similar to how you have raised it in the dataLabels formatter, val contains the value of data.

I leave you below a possible dataLabels and an example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-platform-l6rzys?file=/src/StackedBar.jsx)

```
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    textAnchor: "start",
    style: { colors: ["#fff"] },
    formatter: function (val, opt) {
      console.log("VAL: ", val);
      let valueFormatted = val.toFixed(0);
      console.log("Val formatted: ", valueFormatted);
      // return opt.w.globals.labels[opt.dataPointIndex] + ": " + val;
      return valueFormatted;
    },
    offsetX: 0,
    dropShadow: { enabled: true }
  }
```

Result of the solution in photo with first solution with val

[image]

You can also invent another value within series and put it in the formatter, in the code is the example with **valueInvented**, and in the formatter function we access it with **opt.w.config.series[opt.seriesIndex].valueInvented**

```
const series = [
      {
        name: "Marine Sprite",
        data: [20, 60, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
        valueInvented: 1
      },
      {
        name: "Striking Calf",
        data: [10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
        valueInvented: 2
      },
      {
        name: "Tank Picture",
        data: [10, 5, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
        valueInvented: 3
      },
      {
        name: "Bucket Slope",
        data: [30, 5, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
        valueInvented: 4
      },
      {
        name: "Reborn Kid",
        data: [30, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 25],
        valueInvented: 5
      }
```

];

```
formatter: function (val, opt) {
      console.log("VAL: ", val);
      console.log("OPT:", opt);
      console.log(
        "OPT valueInvented: ",
        opt.w.config.series[opt.seriesIndex].valueInvented
      );
      let valueFormatted = val.toFixed(0);
      console.log("Val formatted: ", valueFormatted);
      return opt.w.config.series[opt.seriesIndex].valueInvented
},
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add a custom formatter as below:

```js
dataLabels: {
  formater(val, opt) {
    return opt.w.globals.series[opt.seriesIndex][opt.dataPointIndex]
  }
}
```